# The required attribute include is empty or missing from the element choose

Tags: c#, .net, csproj

Added conditional reference to csproj file

```
<Choose>
  <When Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug With Project References'">
    <ItemGroup>
      <Reference Include="System.Windows.Forms" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </When>
</Choose>
```

And now have error:

```
The required attribute include is empty or missing from the element choose
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to insert `<Choose>` tag inside `<ItemGroup>`, place it next:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.configuration" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq">
      <RequiredTargetFramework>3.5</RequiredTargetFramework>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Choose>
    <When Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug With Project References'">
      <ItemGroup>
      <Reference Include="System.Windows.Forms" />
      </ItemGroup>
    </When>
  </Choose>
```